# JavaScript: Function that accepts message and replaces specific characters to line of code?

Tags: javascript

I have a chat application on Node.js, I just made smileys for it. 
How can I scan/replace all sets of characters in messages to line of code? (image)

here is the message being added to chat window.

```
$("#chatEntries").append('<div class="messagesOLD">' +
"<span class='msg_date'>"+dateFormat(time)+"</span><span class='msg_seperator'> | </span><span class='msg_name'>"+ pseudo + '</span> : ' + replaceEmoticons(msg) + '</div>');
```

msg is actual message, and replaceEmoticons is function name but it's blank for now as I don't know how to implement it.

Here are my smileys:

```
var smileys = [];
    smileys[":/"] = "derp.png";
    smileys[":)"] = "happy.png";
    smileys[":D"] = "laugh.png";
    smileys[":3"] = "meow.png";
    smileys[":{"] = "must.png";
    smileys[":V"] = "pac.png";
    smileys[":("] = "sad.png";
    smileys[":O"] = "surprised.png";
    smileys[":?"] = "wat.png";
```

The array/object names are the actual char sets I want to be replaced in message. 
All smileys are located like: http://example.com/public/images/smileys/

In the end I want all messages to look like:

```
Hello how are you all doing today? :D
```

would become:

```
Hello how are you all doing today? <img src='http://example.com/public/images/smileys/laugh.png' id='chat_smls'/>
```

Update:

It needs to replace only character sets when there is space before and after them.

So:

Hello:D = Not valid.
 Hello:DHow = Not Valid
 Hello :DHow = Not Valid
 Hello :D How = Valid.

Comment: [Don't abuse arrays!](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/) Use an object: `{}`

Comment: Just changing smileys= [] to smileys = {}; yes?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You can even use a complete object literal then, like `var smileys = {":/":"derp.png", ":)":"happy.png", …};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call replace :

```
function replaceEmoticons(str) {
    for (var key in smileys) {
        var re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + key.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&") + "(?=$|\\s)", 'g');
        str = str.replace(re, "<img src='http://example.com/public/images/smileys/" + smileys[key] + "' id='chat_smls'/>");
    }
    return (str);
}
```

**Here is a demo :**

```js
var smileys = [];
smileys[":/"] = "derp.png";
smileys[":)"] = "happy.png";
smileys[":D"] = "laugh.png";
smileys[":3"] = "meow.png";
smileys[":{"] = "must.png";
smileys[":V"] = "pac.png";
smileys[":("] = "sad.png";
smileys[":O"] = "surprised.png";
smileys[":?"] = "wat.png";

function RegExpEscape(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

function replaceEmoticons(str) {
    for (var key in smileys) {
        var re = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + RegExpEscape(key) + "(?=$|\\s)", 'g');
        str = str.replace(re, "<img src='http://example.com/public/images/smileys/" + smileys[key] + "' id='chat_smls'/>");
    }
    return (str);
}

var delay = (function(){
  var timer = 0;
  return function(callback, ms){
    clearTimeout (timer);
    timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
})();

update();
function update() {
  $('#result').text(replaceEmoticons($('#input').val()));
}

$('#input').keyup(function () {
  delay(update, 250);
});
```

```css
textarea
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Input :</h4>
<textarea id="input">
  Hello how are you all doing today? :D
</textarea>
<hr>
<h4>Result :</h4>
<textarea id="result">
</textarea>
```

**Edited to fulfill requirements**

Comment: this is missing something you want to add /g

Comment: This could replace the `:/` in the `http://` with the derp smiley if the placement in the smileys array is changed.

Comment: I've updated question with specification foro those cases that @OmriAharon mentioned

Comment: I just noticed something by running your code:
If I say enter:
:D Hello? :D 
it only turns first :D into smiley, the other stays as char set.

Comment: Just fixed it. Working on the requirements you added.

Comment: Just updated with the correct regex. Now it should be exactly as you asked.